# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'inWaiting'

Tags: python, matplotlib, serial-port, pyqt5

From the help of the community I was able to install al new backend for matplotlib and run code from the Arduino serial to the output of the python window.

I was then able to make a pretty graph and it displays, but crashes when I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'inWaiting'

**This was remedied by the help of @elethan**

However, I now have the error:

```
pulse =  float(dataArray[0])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

**This error does not happen everytime**

As if that wasn't enough, the output on the plotted graph shows a value of 10 for most of the plot, this is not the value output from the Arduino serial.

I am unsure why:
1) The error is intermittend (maybe its grabbing a ',' and not a value)
2) Why I get a steady value of 10 when the graph does plot

The code is as follows:

```
import time
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from drawnow import *
import os,sys

pulseArray = []

plt.ion()

clippingCounter = 0

# configure the serial connections (the parameters differs on the device you are connecting to)
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate=115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)



ser.isOpen()



input=1

def plotPulseData():

    plt.ylim(0,120)
    plt.title('Plots from data of the Pulse Sensor')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.ylabel('Pulse')
    #plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(pulseArray, 'ro-', label='BPM', linewidth=2)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')



while True:
    #First things first, lets wait for data prior to reading
    time.sleep(1)

    if (ser.inWaiting()>4):

        s = ser.read(4)
        #print ser

        dataArray = s.split(',')
        pulse =  float(dataArray[0])

        pulseArray.append(pulse)

        plt.figure(1)
        drawnow(plotPulseData)
        plt.pause(.000001)

        clippingCounter = clippingCounter + 1

        if(clippingCounter>50):
          pulseArray.pop(0)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure about the nature of the data that you are dealing with. What is happening is that sometimes `dataArray` is going to be a list where the first element (`dataArray[0]` is a string that cannot be converted to a float (i.e., is not something like `'1'` or `'1.0'`. There are ways to handle that, but I am not sure what you want to do instead. If you add `print s` before you assign `pulse`, what kinds of strings do you see?

Comment: I am taking in heart rate data in terms of BPM. The arduino is outputting the correct BPM as per its serial monitor. When adding the 'print s' line I see a bunch of values as I would expect, i.e. 146,
146,
152,
152,
152,
152,
156...
I will have to run this more times to see what is causeing the error. This time around, I got a different error. It was 'bpArray.pop(0)
NameError: name 'bpArray' is not defined'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reassign `ser` the first time through your while loop from a `Serial` object to a string:

```
ser = ser.read(4)
```

The next time through the loop when you call the `inWaiting()` method on that object, you get an error, because you are calling it on a string, instead of the original `Serial` object:

```
ser.inWaiting() > 4
```

Change the variable name for the output of `ser.read(4)` to a name that is not already taken, and this error should go away:

```
s = ser.read(4)
...
dataArray = s.split(',')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This does work, but only intermittently.  Every few times I run the script I either get, some plotted data, then an error; or no execution and just an error; or nothing is plotted (if I change the graphs range, i.e. plt.ylim(0,120)) and the graph runs (and updates) fine.  Maybe somethings wrong with the 'split' ?  I will update my post to reflect.

Comment: Going to make a new post w the new issue. Thank you all for your help.